# how to conditionally include a library

Tags: c++, configuration, gnu, automake

There is a project using protobuf as an option of serialization protocol, but not all the users have protobuf installed. The solution I'm using now is to use `AC_CHECK_LIB[(protobuf)]` in configure.ac, and `if HAVE_PROTOBUF AM_LDFLAGS += -lprotobuf endif` in Makefile.am.
What I want to do now is something like `./bootstrap.sh --enable-protobuf`. Let the user to define whether include the protobuf or not, Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, but I think it's rather painful with autotools. Have you considered leaving autotools and using cmake or scons instead?

Comment: Is that very complicated by autotools? If yes, I'll consider about the tools you mentioned.

Comment: Nah, it's not extremely complicated, but I think it's very, very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Read about AC_ARG_ENABLE in the autoconf manual.